# How to chain more than 23 elements in a tuple in Scala Cats?

Tags: scala, scala-cats, cats-effect

In Scala I am making use of the Cats Library and I am using the mapN() function. Lets say I have created the following case class with 22 elements. The following code will work without any problem.

```
case class Example1 (element1: String , element2: String ..... element22)
('string1', ...'string22').mapN(Example1.apply)
```

Lets say I want a element23. But unfortunately the compiler will complain that there are arguments missing because the mapping is not done correctly. Is there any way of chaining the 23rd element because I saw that there is a tuple of max 22 elements handled by the mapN() function.

Comment: The recommended advice is to group the fields in inner tuples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no support for `mapN` for tuples of arity > 22. One could probably change that in cats by fiddling around with `maxArity` [here](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/main/project/Boilerplate.scala#L55) (though that would require doing that for Scala 3 only).

However: for your specific use case (converting tuples to a case class), Scala 3 (which I assume you are using because Scala 2 does not support tuples of arity > 22) would offer a simple solution: see [Converting between tuples and case classes in Scala 3](https://taig.medium.com/converting-between-tuples-and-case-classes-in-scala-3-7079ccedf4c0) and this [runnable scastie example](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/4CbRCMHcRdi9a5LF3p7N7w).

Comment: Yeah I looked a bit into this and apparently there is no way to do it with mapN. But one can use  'for yield' construct for the same thing. I am gonna for this option.